# DRF reverse for 'user-create' not found

Tags: python, django, authentication, testing, django-rest-framework

Got a view named MyUserCreate and in app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'api/users^$', views.MyUserCreate.as_view(), name='user-create'),
]
```

This is my root urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from rest_framework import permissions
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title="Snippets API",
      default_version='v1',
      description="Test description",
      terms_of_service="https://www.google.com/policies/terms/",
      contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
      license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
   ),
   public=True,
   permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
)

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    re_path(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    re_path(r'^redoc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),

    path('test/', include('test_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #path('user/', include('user.urls'))
]
```

In app/tests.py

```
self.create_url = reverse('user-create')
```

Running

```
python manage.py test
```

Gives this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\COVID19-be\django_server\user\tests.py",
>   line 13, in setUp
>       self.create_url = reverse('user-create')   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py",
>   line 87, in reverse
>       return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\letsgo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
>       raise NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'user-create' not found. 'user-create' is not a valid view
>   function or pattern name.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: can you show your root urls.py?

Comment: Sure, already there @ArakkalAbu

Comment: seems like you have commented out the line, `#path('user/', include('user.urls'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the app URLs in the ***root URLs*** config

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other URLs

    path('user/', include('user.urls'))
]
```